# mysql - How to remove duplicate rows in parent table and leave one row with the lowest ID, and replace foreign key in child's table with this ID?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, php, duplication, replace

I have the situation where I have three tables:

```
hgn_modern_sources
+----+--------------+
| id |    source    |
+----+--------------+
| 17 | Something... |
+----+--------------+

junc_modern_source_has_reference
+----+------------------+------------------------+
| id | modern_source_id | location_within_source |
+----+------------------+------------------------+
| 52 |               17 | 1, 1                   |
| 89 |               17 | 1, 1                   |
| 99 |               17 | 1, 1                   |
+----+------------------+------------------------+

hgn_picture_has_reference
+----+---------------------+-------------------+
| id | modern_reference_id | picture_link      |
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
| 45 | 89                  | /images/image1.png |
| 75 | 99                  | /images/image2.png |
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
```

My question is how to delete duplicates from `junc_modern_source_has_reference` (id = 89 and id = 99), leave one row with the lowest ID (id = 52), and replace foreign keys in `hgn_picture_has_reference` table (column `modern_reference_id`) with one left (id = 52)?

The solution can be only MySQL based, or PHP + MySQL (which I prefer more).

Comment: what version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 or similar. It is a trivial task, but I don't feel like creating the test data and tables to verify

Comment: I use MySQL 8.0.

Comment: @Lennart I got some errors with that fiddle, it throw error "Run failed". I will try from my home PC.

Comment: Yes, I noticed. I'll post an untested solution that should work even for earlier versions of MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitions and sample data, either provide a fiddle or definitions and sample data as below, to get more attraction to your question:

```
create table junc_modern_source_has_reference
( id int not null primary key
, modern_source_id int not null
);

insert into junc_modern_source_has_reference
values (52,17),(89,17),(99,17);

create table hgn_picture_has_reference
( id int not null primary key
, modern_reference_id int not null
);

insert into hgn_picture_has_reference
values (45,89),(75,99);
```

First step is to update all rows to the lowest id:

```
update  hgn_picture_has_reference x
   set modern_reference_id = (select min(y.id) 
                              from junc_modern_source_has_reference y
                              join junc_modern_source_has_reference z
                                  on y.modern_source_id = z.modern_source_id
                              where x.modern_reference_id = z.id )
where exists (
    select min(y.id) 
    from junc_modern_source_has_reference y
    join junc_modern_source_has_reference z
        on y.modern_source_id = z.modern_source_id
    where x.modern_reference_id = z.id 
);
```

Now we can delete all but the lowest id, this is non-standard SQL, but MySQL used to have problems referencing the table under modification:

```
delete x.*
from junc_modern_source_has_reference x
join junc_modern_source_has_reference y
    on x.modern_source_id = y.modern_source_id
   and y.id < x.id
;
```

A standard version would be something like:

```
delete x.*
from junc_modern_source_has_reference x
where exists (
    select 1 from junc_modern_source_has_reference y
    where  x.modern_source_id = y.modern_source_id
      and y.id < x.id
);
```

I.e. delete row if there is another row with lower id for the same modern_source_id

Comment: Thank you @Lennart for your answer and explanation. I understood it quite well and I will accomodate your solution to my case.

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempTable; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable
(id int
,minId int
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- filling temporary table with list of duplicate ids 
-- and corresponding minimal id within each group of duplicates
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT id
    ,MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY modern_source_id, location_within_source ) AS minId
    ,ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY modern_source_id, location_within_source ORDER BY id) AS rn
FROM junc_modern_source_has_reference
)
INSERT INTO tempTable (id, minId)
SELECT id, minId FROM CTE WHERE rn > 1;

UPDATE hgn_picture_has_reference AS t1
JOIN tempTable AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.modern_reference_id  = t2.minId;


DELETE t1
FROM junc_modern_source_has_reference AS t1
JOIN tempTable AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable;
```

If you use MySQL version older than 8.0 you can't use window functions and you need to modify part with CTE this way:

```
INSERT INTO tempTable (id, minId)
SELECT id, minId 
FROM 
    (SELECT t1.id
            ,t2.minId
    FROM junc_modern_source_has_reference AS t1
    JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(id) AS minId
            ,modern_source_id
            ,location_within_source
        FROM junc_modern_source_has_reference
        GROUP BY modern_source_id, location_within_source
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
        ) AS t2 ON t1.modern_source_id = t2.modern_source_id 
                   AND t1.location_within_source = t2.location_within_source
                   AND t1.id <> t2.minId
    ) AS CTE
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Can you explain me how this work? I never used PARTITION or CTE before.

Comment: @BorisJ. CTE is just a common table expression (alias for subquery, you can use any name). "PARTITION BY" is a part of "OVER" clause. I used window fucntions to get minimal id within each group pointed in "PARTITION BY" and to get row number for each id within each group. If group contains more than one row then we want to delete all rows with row number greater than 1.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Your answer is good, but Lennart's is much simpler for me to understand.

Comment: @BorisJ.Lennart's answer is good too but I suppose it will make more reads and if you have a large tables it will affect the performance.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that. That is very important. I will do some tests to see how it works.

Comment: @BorisJ. Also you may see that we used different columns to determine which rows are duplicates. He used only modern_source_id, I used modern_source_id and location_within_source together. In your example our queries produces similar resluts but on your real dataset it may be different and I don't know which one is correct for you (you may need to adjust my or Lennart's code)

Comment: Thank you for that, I would certainly use both ``modern_source_id`` and ``location_within_source`` for duplicates search and replace.